# How to plot scatter with different edgecolor defined by an array ranged -0.1 to 0.1

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

```
def scatterplot(part):
    colors = part['deltf']
    c = plt.cm.coolwarm(colors)
    plt.scatter(part['fnormal'], part['mu']/part['E'], c='w',edgecolors=c,alpha=0.5, 
                   cmap='coolwarm', marker="o")
```

The edge color only has one color on the output figure by running this code. I found `plt.cm.coolwarm` need positive value, but I need negative value presented.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: You need a norm to transform your values to the range 0..1. For example `norm = plt.Normalize(min(colors), max(colors)` and then `c = plt.cm.coolwarm(norm(colors))`. If you need zero at the center, you could use something like `norm = plt.Normalize(-max(colors), max(colors)`

Comment: Hi, JohanC. Thanks for your quick answer. I will try it.

Comment: @ted930511 's answer just re-creates `plt.Normalize` manually. It's the same functionality, but might be easier to understand as it shows the full implementation (somewhat simplified, as it doesn't check for special cases, such as minimum and maximum possibly equal).

Comment: As @ JohanC points out, the key message here is to normalize to the range [0, 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to normalize values to [0, 1] to map the color. pls see code below:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

xx = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, 100)

def normalize(xx):
    vmin = xx.min()
    vmax = xx.max()
    return (xx - vmin)/(vmax-vmin)

cmap = mpl.cm.coolwarm
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-0.1, vmax=0.1)
    
def scatterplot(xx):
    colors = normalize(xx)
    c = plt.cm.coolwarm(colors)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
    ax.scatter(xx, np.sin(xx), c='w',edgecolors=c,alpha=0.5, cmap='coolwarm', marker="o")
    cbar = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax)
scatterplot(xx)
```

**Summary**:

- to map color, use normalized values
- to plot data, use original values

[image]

Comment: Hi, ted930511. Thank you for such quick. Could you add colorbar with a real range?

Comment: This actually should be asked on another SO question, but anyway, I updated the code get what you want, enjoy:).

Comment: Pls kindly accept the answer if your issue is solved. thx